# How to connect ViewController with view by MVC pattern

Tags: ios, swift

I have two classes:

```
BoardViewController: ViewController
BoardView: UIView
```

`BoardView` is main view for `BoardViewController` and I set it like this:

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    let view = BoardView(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.view = view
}
```

`BoardView` containing `UITableView` and `UIRefreshControl`

And now I'm wondering how to do it in best practice:

1. Set `dataSource` for `tableView`:

   Make a var for controller in `BoardView` and set it from `BoardViewController` in this loadView or using `self.view.tableView.dataSource = self` in controller ?
2. Where I should store func for UIRefreshContorler action, in View or ViewController? This func containing request for data to tableView

Answer (score 0):

inside BoardViewController create an instance of Board View

```
private let boardView = BoardView()
```

and set it as the current view inside loadView():

```
view = searchView
```

Add init() func to BoardView

```
init() {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    // some function to create tableView, set constraints etc.
}
```

And then tap into its properties inside BoardViewController e.g.:

```
boardView.tableView.delegate = self
```

Here (inside BoardViewController) do:

```
extension BoardViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
 // declare all the functions
}
```